Authorization test with spring-boot security and thymeleaf controller
I have a method in my controller that just allow user with ADMIN role, and want to do a test for it (*I'm using thymeleaf)
This is my controller method:
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String admin(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    String nomeUsuario = session.getAttribute("nome_usuario").toString();
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.buscarPorNomeUsuario(nomeUsuario);

    if (usuario == null) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    model.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);

    return "login/home";
}

My securityConfig implementation
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String ROLE_USUARIO_COMUM = "USUARIO_COMUM";

    @Autowired
    private IUsuario usuarioRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)
                        .anyRequest().hasRole(ROLE_USUARIO_COMUM))
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login/**").permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .permitAll())
                .addFilterBefore(new TokenValidationFilter(usuarioRepository),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

}

And my test
@WebMvcTest(LoginController.class)
public class LoginControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN") 
    public void testAdminAccessWithAdminRole() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk()) 
               .andExpect(view().name("login/home"));
    }
}

But when I run this test, the method testAdminAccessWithAdminRole() return expected status 302

302 is a redirect, why should it be different? Also I doubt your login page is /login/** as that simply doesn't make sense. It should point to a full URL. Next to that why are you doing user checking in your controller, that kind of beats the purpose of using Spring Boot in the first place.

You are right about user verification and I took it back. I changed the test to wait for the redirection and check if it is redirecting to http://localhost/admin, but the test expects the destination url to be http://localhost/login, even though I pass a user with the ADMIN role.
.andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()) 
.andExpect(redirectedUrl("http://localhost/home"));

It should redirect to /login as that is what you configured. When you aren't logged in when access a protected URL it will redirect to the login page.

And can I simulate an authenticated user in the test?
